# What do the result dataframe's columns of a Deequ check signify?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, amazon-deequ

So, I ran a simple Deequ check in Spark, that went something like this :

```
val verificationResult: VerificationResult = { VerificationSuite()
  .onData(dataset)
  .addCheck(
    Check(CheckLevel.Error, "Review Check")
      .isComplete("col1")
      .isUnique("col2")
      .hasSize(_ == count_date)
      .satisfies(
          "abs(col4 - col5) <= 0.20 * col5",
          "value(col4) lies between value(col5)-20% and value(col5)+20%"
    )
  .run()
}

val result1 = checkResultsAsDataFrame(spark, verificationResult)
```

Now, my `result1` dataframe looks something like this:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|       check|check_level|check_status|          constraint|constraint_status|  constraint_message|
+------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|Review Check|      Error|       Error|CompletenessConst...|          Success|                    |
|Review Check|      Error|       Error|UniquenessConstra...|          Failure|Value: 7.62664794...|
|Review Check|      Error|       Error|SizeConstraint(Si...|          Success|                    |
|Review Check|      Error|     Success|ComplianceConstra...|          Success|                    |
+------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

I'm confused between the columns `check_status` and `constraint_status`. How are they different? The results of my checks should be in the latter one right? Then what does the former imply?

I couldn't find any clarity on this in the [deequ blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/test-data-quality-at-scale-with-deequ/) either. Could someone please explain?

Comment: Could you print with `result1.show(truncate=false)` to show all of the column contents?

Comment: It's a little big for here, I'm afraid, might make this clumsy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`check_status` is the overal status for the `Check` group you run. It depends on the `CheckLevel` and the constraint status. If you look at the [code](https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/blob/b5566afba92d17a735e456236568d0ec91e92bcd/src/main/scala/com/amazon/deequ/checks/Check.scala#L1036) :

```
val anyFailures = constraintResults.exists { _.status == ConstraintStatus.Failure }

val checkStatus = (anyFailures, level) match {
  case (true, CheckLevel.Error) => CheckStatus.Error
  case (true, CheckLevel.Warning) => CheckStatus.Warning
  case (_, _) => CheckStatus.Success
}
```

If there is any failure in the constraints then `check_status = CheckLevel`. Else it's a success.